# Android widget want to restrict to display in small screen market

Tags: android

I had developed a full screen size widget and i want to install it only in Large screen devices. It should not even want to display in small screen market. Anybody knows how can i restrict my widget to not to display in small screen market. Suggestions are welcome. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="false"
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

in the Android Manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html) out. It's the official Google Play way of restricting app configurations.